# Floated Div Columns, Left-Most Fixed

Tags: css-float, html, css-position

I'd like to have a div floated to the left *that is fixed* but still another div float next to it (i.e., two coumns, but the left-most remains in place when page is scrolled).

As far as I've been able to tell, [fixed and position don't mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568548/div-with-fixed-positioning-and-float), and one can only do this by, e.g., adding a margin-left to th second (right-most) div to achieve this, ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661310/how-to-make-the-leftmost-of-many-other-left-floated-fixed-width-divs-occupy-rema))

But, I retain a glimmering hope I bring here to be either stoked or snuffed out.

So, I'd like to change the css here so that I can take out the margin-left tag and just have that #body div float up against the #menu one:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    #menu
    {
    float:left; width: 10em; position: fixed;
    }

    #body
    {
    float:left; maring-left: 10em;
    }

    #footer
    {
    clear:both;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div /*main div others are nested in*/>

    <div id="menu">
    menu<br/>menu<br/>menu<br/>menu<br/>menu<br/>menu<br/>menu<br/>menu<br/>menu<br/>menu<br/>menu<br/>menu

    </div>
    <div id="body">
    <p>
    body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body 
    </p>

    <div id="footer">
    footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you all for any help!

Comment: maring-left must bei margin-left

Comment: The only way is with Margin-left

Answer (score 0):

spelling error on margin left 
ttp://jsfiddle.net/BYMZD/